# How to use /etc/paths.d to add executable files to my path?

Tags: macos, path

I am trying to use /etc/paths.d to add an executable to my path variable but I have no success so far.

The full path of the executable file is: `/opt/ImageMagick/bin/convert`

/etc/paths.d contains two files: 40-XQuartz and ImageMagick

The 40-XQuartz contains one line: `/opt/X11/bin`
The ImageMagick contains one line: `/opt/ImageMagick/bin`

My `echo $PATH` gives:

`/Users/Administrator/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Administrator/.rbenv/bin:/Users/Administrator/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`

So it seems that only the first file (40-XQuartz) does its job.
The permissions of the two files (40-XQuartz and ImageMagick) are exactly the same so my question is why the first one works and the second one is not.

I am running OS X Mavericks.

Comment: What shell do you use? What's about /etc/paths?

Comment: Adding stiff to `/etc/paths.d` works for me, but I restart whatever terminal application I am using (ITerm2 in my case) for the new path to take effect

Answer (score 23):

Have you started a new login shell since adding the new file for ImageMagick? The setting of the path from `paths.d` entries is done in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/csh.login`, so you need to start a new shell for the new entries to take effect.

OS X uses `path_helper` to set the path based on the files in `/etc/paths.d` - you can always call it manually (assuming a Bourne-like shell here):

```
$ eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
```

Comment: Of course I have started a new shell.I even restarted my mac.

Comment: new login shell worked for me

Comment: @mjturner when using your command it reorders my paths putting paths I have in `.bash_profile` below the paths that are in `etc/paths.d`. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @John What do you have in `.bash_profile'? You may need to adjust how you set `PATH` so that your preferred directories are first.

Comment: 1. `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
2. `export PATH`
3.  `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/nano/bin`
4. `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`

Comment: From the man page. `NOTE The path_helper utility should not be invoked directly.  It is intended only for use by the shell profile.`

Answer (score 4):

Running

```
echo /opt/ImageMagick/bin|sudo tee /etc/paths.d/ImageMagick;bash -l;echo $PATH
```

adds `/opt/ImageMagick/bin` to `PATH` on my installation.

Are you overriding `PATH` in some other place like `~/.bash_profile`?

The paths in `/etc/paths.d/` are added to the path by `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, which is run from `/etc/profile`, `/etc/zsh.env`, and `/etc/csh.login`. `path_helper` is not run by graphical applications or when bash is invoked as a non-login shell.

You can also set a default `PATH` in `/etc/launchd.conf`:

1. Run for example `setenv PATH /Users/Administrator/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Administrator/.rbenv/bin:/Users/Administrator/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin|sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf`.
2. Either restart, or run `launchctl</etc/launchd.conf;sudo launchctl</etc/launchd.conf` and relaunch processes.

I prefer changing the path in `/etc/launchd.conf`, because it also affects programs that are not started from shells, like text editors and programs started by launchd jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, I was just playing around with adding ImageMagic to my Mac.  Not only do you need `ImageMagick/bin` in your `PATH`, you also need an environment variable set, or added to:

To test you can create it manually with:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY=".:/opt/ImageMagic/lib"
```

Information for setting an environment variable for Mac OS can be found here, [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)